# How to make scroll view stop moving when dragging on it and resume moving immediately for the already touching finger?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

How can I make the scroll view stop moving when dragging on it, after that, how can I make it start scrolling immediately when finger already touching the scroll view?

```
self.scrollView.notMovingWhileDragging()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    self.scrollView.resumeMovingForTheAlreadyTouchingFinger()
}
```

For the above two functions, I set `isScrollEnabled` to `false` then `true`, but the scroll view not move if finger already touching it when above callback is called.

The result I want is like the iOS Maps app, when the sheet is on top, and the scroll view is been dragged a little distance from top. Now I start dragging down the scroll view, scroll view move down, when scroll view is been scroll to top, then keep dragging down, the sheet down(scroll view stop moving when dragging), then dragging up, the sheet view up, and when the sheet view is on top, keep dragging up, the scroll view start scrolling again (scroll view resume moving when finger already on it).

Comment: Show your code please.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The `isScrollEnabled` property of a `UIScrollView` simply updates the `isEnabled` property of the `UIScrollView`'s `panGesture`. `UIPanGesture` has a defined lifecycle that begins with `touchesBegan` as a touch down. and its state moves to `.began`, so enabling it while a touch has already begun will not cause it to fire.

In your original question you asked how to allow scrolling after handling the positioning of a sheet-style interface a la Apple Maps. This can be done by adding a target your scroll view's `panGesture`. For example, you can add a target like so `tableView.panGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))`; then in your action you can say something like:

```
@objc func handlePan(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let velocity = sender.velocity(in: view)
    let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
    switch  sender.state {
    case .began: break
    case .changed:
        // shouldMoveSheet can check to see if the sheet should move or scroll view should scroll based on content offset, pan translation, etc.
        if shouldMoveSheet(for: translation) {
            bottomConstraint.constant = newConstant
            // while moving sheet set the content offset to the top so the scroll view does not scroll
            tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: tableView.adjustedContentInset.top), animated: false)
            sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: view)
        }

    case .ended:
        // Depending on if the sheet has been moved when the gesture ends move the sheet to the up or down position
        if velocity.y < 0 && tableView.contentOffset.y <= tableView.adjustedContentInset.top {
            bottomConstraint.constant = constantForSheetUp
        } else if tableView.contentOffset.y <= tableView.adjustedContentInset.top {
            bottomConstraint.constant = constantForSheetDown
        }
        UIView.animate(duration: 0.3) {
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    case .failed, .cancelled, .possible:
        break
    }
}
```

Which will enable a pan up to some threshold then scrolling:

[image]

Comment: This seems works, but only when dragging slowly, when dragging the entire table view quickly and keep changing the content offset to a constant value, the content of table view will move not at the same speed of the moving table view(it look obviously when table view has a fixed subview or has a moving together superview), the result is it looks a little lag when dragging.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want. Is the animation shown not what you are talking about? Because, for me, it doesn't matter the speed at which the gesture is performed. I'm quite certain this is how it is done the maps app.